# Compiling/linking Objective-C project with implementation of a C library

Tags: objective-c

I have the following situation:

- I have code from a project written essentially in C, designed to be compiled against a 3rd party library that interfaced with iOS-- so I basically have some C code, plus a header file defining prototypes for calls such as AddImageAtThisPosition(), PlayMP3() etc -- just to be clear, all of the code/header files that I have are "pure C";
- I'm building a new project in Xcode, in which I have imported this old C code, and in which I am now writing my own implementations of AddImageAtThisPosition() etc, whose implementations obviously need to be in Objective-C.

I have put my implementations in a .m file, which I believe is supposed to be the correct place to put "some C code that calls Objective-C methods". Everything *compiles* OK, but at link time:

- my functions defined in the .m file aren't apparently being found -- I assume there's some extra thing I need to do in Xcode to say "please actually link the resulting object file from this .m file" -- where is this option or what else do I need to do?
- when I try to call the C function ThisFunction() from other Objective C class, I get a link-time error of that the function _ThisFunction() cannot be found. I assume this is some name mangling that happens during compilation -- so can anyone tell me what I need to do to make the C function be correctly found when called from within an Objective C method?

Comment: rename .m file to .mm

Comment: Why do you need to reimplement these functions? You can use pure-C from Objective-C.

Comment: .mm Is for Objective-C++, @rahul_send89. From the description, .m is the correct choice.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Because (a) they were originally defined in a third party library to which I don't have the source code, and (b) I specifically want to write my own implementation for various reasons, e.g. because the original implementation uses UIViews to display images and I want to use SpriteKit...

Comment: Okay, just wasn't sure if you thought they couldn't be used otherwise for some reason.

Comment: Are the files in the "Compile Sources" list of your Project Settings? http://i.stack.imgur.com/BWyzM.png

Comment: Please post an example with a function implementation, header prototype and actual error message. Make sure .m is checked for current target (right pane).

Comment: The .m files and legacy .cpp file are included "compile sources" and checked for the current target.

Comment: did you said .cpp file? you may need `extern "C"` in header

Comment: Doh! Thank you -- it's looking like it could just be the missing extern "C"!

Comment: @BryanChen That was actually the problem! For some reason I'd previously had trouble using extern "C" in Objective-C, but I think this was because I'd forgotten the #ifdef __cplusplus. If you want to add this as an answer, then I'll select it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement the function in .cpp file, you need `extern "C"` in header to expose them to C/ObjC.

The easiest way is to wrap header with `__BEGIN_DECLS` and `__END_DECLS` macros from `cdefs.h`